# Fill in name column based on which sheet is being imported

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a Google sheet which imports tracking numbers from multiple other sheets and different information from each.  I am able to do that part but is it possible to assign a name to each sheet being imported and have the name displayed in a cell on the row?

I hope this isn't super confusing, I am providing a sample document below.  I am importing information from Tom and Brent sheets into Master Sheet.  I would like column B of the master sheet to say which sheet the import is coming from.  Any thoughts?

Master Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10YnvyaK_ODWZpVoYMMItOr6Dr9j2Gy--aJ3d4hegVi4/edit#gid=0

Tom Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wnxnhRkTiLtut7Ej9kE-NH6GrK0S3St5f3snsr4KR_I/edit#gid=0

Brent Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X5VNVWkjP7ELy2Vuj5uzuK9fB6l1U9Wh9W3ORDkcxA8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT({
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1wnxnhRkTiLtut7Ej9kE-NH6GrK0S3St5f3snsr4KR_I","Sheet1!A2:C"),
 "select Col1 where Col2 like '%USPS%'")&"♦Tom";
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1X5VNVWkjP7ELy2Vuj5uzuK9fB6l1U9Wh9W3ORDkcxA8","Sheet1!A2:C"),
 "select Col1 where Col2 like '%USPS%'")&"♦Brent"}, "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The only question I have now is how to sort column A by date.  I used this in the old formula order by Col1 asc at the end of the query but that wont work now because adding that to each query will only sort the data coming from each sheet.

Comment: try: `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT({
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1wnxnhRkTiLtut7Ej9kE-NH6GrK0S3St5f3snsr4KR_I","Sheet1!A2:C"),
 "select Col1 where Col2 like '%USPS%'")&"♦Tom";
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1X5VNVWkjP7ELy2Vuj5uzuK9fB6l1U9Wh9W3ORDkcxA8","Sheet1!A2:C"),
 "select Col1 where Col2 like '%USPS%'")&"♦Brent"}, "♦")), "order by Col1 asc", 0)`